# Opened file with several million lines: how to close it?

Tags: terminal, editors, process-management

I've just accidentally opened rockyou.txt in Kali Linux on a fairly slow computer. It has now been sitting on the desktop loading the 30million words for over an hour. It is not frozen, as I can still use the mouse, and the clock display is still changing, however, I cannot cancel, close or open anything else. Is there anyway I can close it or kill it without having to restart?

I was also wondering if there is anyway of searching for a specific word within rockyou, like an online database, instead of loading it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>?

Comment: You can use `grep "word" rockyou`, `awk '/word/' rockyou` or `sed -n '/word/p' rockyou` to lookup a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to go to the terminal by typing Ctrl-Alt-F1, logging in and searching for offender with `top`, then remembering it's name or pid and killing it:

- by pid: `kill -KILL pid`
- by name: `pkill -KILL -f name`

SIGKILL will make it go away if it's not hanged "inside kernel", i.e. there is bad syscall which does not release the task back to you into userspace. Such situations occur when the program is doing large disk I/O.

If it's not even possible, then only Alt-SysRQ can help, or even logging in remotely (if remote service such as ssh was enabled). Many sites refer to trying Alt-SysRQ-R, but it never worked for me well with X11 (and Ctrl-Alt-Backspace thing, perhaps it is disabled by default). Another try is to kill everything with Alt-SysRQ-E/I, but it will kill everything, not just the offender.

If all these ways were exhausted, then, only hard reset.

It's also possible that kernel will kill it automatically with OOM killer mechanism (since it tries to load much words inside memory).

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl-alt-backspace for killing the x-server, which cancels all open session too.

If not possible, try logging in remotely from another computer via ssh, and kill the editor with "kill -9 .

Comment: Thanks Gerhard, I will try this eventually if I don't get any other answers. I do have a lot of terminals with a lot of good stuff running in the background, so I don't really want to kill everything!

Comment: Or ctrl-alt-F1 log as root and kill the process